# Submitting Transaction with CSL Metadata Isn't Showing

Tags: metadata, cardano-serialization-lib, transaction-metadata

I've forked a dApp Connector I found on Github and I'm trying to add some transaction metadata to the ADA transaction it builds. This is what I currently have:

```
buildSendADATransaction = async () => {
    //metadata
    const messageData = {
      receiver_id: "SJKdj34k3jjKFDKfjFUDfdjkfd",
      sender_id: "jkfdsufjdk34h3Sdfjdhfduf873",
      comment: "happy birthday",
      tags: [0, 264, -1024, 32],
    };
    const generalMetadata = GeneralTransactionMetadata.new();
    console.log(Buffer.from(generalMetadata.to_bytes(), "hex").toString("hex"));

    generalMetadata.insert(
      BigNum.from_str("674"),
      encode_json_str_to_metadatum(JSON.stringify(messageData))
    );
    const _metadata = AuxiliaryData.new();
    _metadata.set_metadata(generalMetadata);

    console.log(`the metadata is ${_metadata.metadata()}`);

    // build tx
    const txBuilder = await this.initTransactionBuilder();

    const shelleyOutputAddress = Address.from_bech32(
      this.state.addressBech32SendADA
    );
    const shelleyChangeAddress = Address.from_bech32(this.state.changeAddress);

    txBuilder.add_output(
      TransactionOutput.new(
        shelleyOutputAddress,
        Value.new(BigNum.from_str(this.state.lovelaceToSend.toString()))
      )
    );

    // Find the available UTXOs in the wallet and
    // use them as Inputs
    const txUnspentOutputs = await this.getTxUnspentOutputs();
    txBuilder.add_inputs_from(txUnspentOutputs, 1);

    // calculate the min fee required and send any change to an address
    txBuilder.add_change_if_needed(shelleyChangeAddress);

    // once the transaction is ready, we build it to get the tx body without witnesses
    const txBody = txBuilder.build();
    txBody.set_auxiliary_data_hash(hash_auxiliary_data(_metadata));

    // Tx witness
    const transactionWitnessSet = TransactionWitnessSet.new();

    const tx = Transaction.new(
      txBody,
      TransactionWitnessSet.from_bytes(transactionWitnessSet.to_bytes()),
      _metadata
    );

    let txVkeyWitnesses = await this.API.signTx(
      Buffer.from(tx.to_bytes(), "utf8").toString("hex"),
      true
    );
    txVkeyWitnesses = TransactionWitnessSet.from_bytes(
      Buffer.from(txVkeyWitnesses, "hex")
    );

    transactionWitnessSet.set_vkeys(txVkeyWitnesses.vkeys());

    const txBodyFinal = tx.body();
    const signedTx = Transaction.new(
      txBodyFinal,
      transactionWitnessSet,
      _metadata
    );

    const submittedTxHash = await this.API.submitTx(
      Buffer.from(signedTx.to_bytes(), "utf8").toString("hex")
    );
    console.log(submittedTxHash);
    this.setState({ submittedTxHash });
  };
```

It constructs the transaction just fine with a wallet like Nami, but there's no metadata attached to that transaction. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to integrating with wallets other than Nami Wallet,

Typhon Wallet DApp connector has simple, ready-to-call methods to build a transaction with metadata and/or tokens.

Below is transaction method that adds metadata to a transaction.

```
const auxiliaryDataCbor = typhonjs.utils
  .createAuxiliaryDataCbor({
    metadata: [
      {
        label: 674,
        data: {
          msg: ["This is a comment for the transaction xyz, thank you very much!"],
        },
      },
    ],
  })
  .toString("hex");

const paymentTransactionResponse = await typhon.paymentTransaction({
  auxiliaryDataCbor: auxiliaryDataCbor,
  outputs: [
    {
      address:
        "addr_test1qz7jw975stagnvs00wsjny6y6gpazn86yvwcm2vy02j3up7mt68vuzvz4nzgs00x0shrgywvy674v6r2zcs8fxvvq27qfjq8np",
      amount: "6000000",
    },
  ],
});
```

Example at https://docs.typhonwallet.io/examples/paymentTransaction.html#sending-metadata

https://typhonwallet.io

Comment: Yeah, I saw that -- but I'd prefer to stick with CSL, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is refferenced from https://cardanoupdates.com/commits/6af4284b32841a13ebe86fdcc6f10dd1d74ddfdc and I have used similar code in production. I haven't tested this function but you should get the idea.

```
buildSendADATransaction = async () => {
const messageData = {
    receiver_id: "SJKdj34k3jjKFDKfjFUDfdjkfd",
    sender_id: "jkfdsufjdk34h3Sdfjdhfduf873",
    comment: "happy birthday",
    tags: [0, 264, -1024, 32],
};

const txBuilder = await this.initTransactionBuilder();
const shelleyOutputAddress = Address.from_bech32(
    this.state.addressBech32SendADA
);
const shelleyChangeAddress = Address.from_bech32(this.state.changeAddress);

txBuilder.add_output(
    TransactionOutput.new(
        shelleyOutputAddress,
        Value.new(BigNum.from_str(this.state.lovelaceToSend.toString()))
    )
);

/////////////////////////////////
// Add metadata here

txBuilder.add_json_metadatum(
    BigNum.from_str("674"),
    JSON.stringify(messageData)
);
/////////////////////////////////


const txUnspentOutputs = await this.getTxUnspentOutputs();
txBuilder.add_inputs_from(txUnspentOutputs, 1);
txBuilder.add_change_if_needed(shelleyChangeAddress);
const txBody = txBuilder.build();

////////////////////////////
// Create unsigned tx with metadata included

const unsignedTransaction = txBuilder.build_tx();
/////////////////////////////

const transactionWitnessSet = TransactionWitnessSet.new();
const tx = Transaction.new(
    txBody,
    TransactionWitnessSet.from_bytes(transactionWitnessSet.to_bytes()),
    ///
    unsignedTransaction.auxiliary_data() // Include metadata

);
let txVkeyWitnesses = await this.API.signTx(
    Buffer.from(tx.to_bytes(), "utf8").toString("hex"),
    true
);
txVkeyWitnesses = TransactionWitnessSet.from_bytes(
    Buffer.from(txVkeyWitnesses, "hex")
);
transactionWitnessSet.set_vkeys(txVkeyWitnesses.vkeys());

const txBodyFinal = tx.body();
const signedTx = Transaction.new(
    txBodyFinal, 
    transactionWitnessSet,
    ///
    unsignedTransaction.auxiliary_data() // Include metadata

);

const submittedTxHash = await this.API.submitTx(
    Buffer.from(signedTx.to_bytes(), "utf8").toString("hex")
);
console.log(submittedTxHash);
this.setState({ submittedTxHash });};
```